# Python Lottery Number Generation

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

I am working on a lottery number generation program. I have a fixed list of allowed numbers (1-80) from which users can choose 6 numbers. Each number can only be picked once. I want to generate all possible combinations efficiently.  Current implementation takes more than 30 seconds if allowed_numbers is [1,...,60]. Above that, it freezes my system.

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np


LOT_SIZE = 6


allowed_numbers = np.arange(1, 61)
all_combinations = np.array(list(combinations(allowed_numbers, LOT_SIZE)))
print(len(all_combinations))
```

I think I would need a numpy array (not sure if 2D). Something like,

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],
[1,2,3,4,5,,7],...]
```

because I want to (quickly) perform several operations on these combinations. These operations may include,

- Removing combinations that have only even numbers
- Removing combinations who's sum is greater than 150 etc.
- Checking if there is only one pair of consecutive numbers (Acceptable: [1,2,4,6,8,10] {Pair: (1,2)}| Not-acceptable: [1,2,4,5,7,9] {Pairs: (1,2) and (4,5)} )

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Create the combinations only once and store it in `text` file.  For later part you just have to read the data from file and perform operations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the script freezes my system if I try to generate a list of more than 60 numbers (which is what I need).

Comment: Note that in your case you have 61!/(6!55!) which is ~10e70. You will never really store it or be able to process.

Comment: 60C6 is approximately 5e7, which is definitely storable, though may not ever be particularly fast to generate.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. The generation of combinations or the operations on them?

Comment: Sorry, I read the question wrong. I thought there is 6C60

Comment: @Federico it is generation of combinations. But I want the output data structure to be able to handle the operations.

Comment: I don't understand. This method it's the fastest one. To improve the performance, you can maybe use the `iterator` that `combinations` return instead of converting it to a `list`.

Comment: @FedericoDomeniconi I tried this `np.array(combinations(allowed_numbers, LOT_SIZE))` but it gives this error "TypeError: len() of unsized object". Any hint on how to create arrays of 6 items?

Comment: Because you should iter on it with `next(combinations(allowed_numbers, LOT_SIZE))` that gives you the next item each time you call it until it throws `StopIteration`

Comment: Is there a reason you want to get "all" possible combinations? For practical purposes, when you have too many of combinations it is generally better to create a random sampler and apply the filters you need

Comment: @Mstaino that does seems logical. But I have to apply over 200 filtering rules (like those mentioned in the post) on the combinations. So I just thought it would be easy to get all then keep filtering till I have the desired combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1) apply filters on the iterable instead of on the data, using `filter`:

```
def filt(x):
    return sum(x) < 7

list(filter(filt, itertools.combinations(allowed, n)))
```

will save ~15% time vs. constructing the list and applying the filters then, i.e.:

```
[i for i in itertools.combinations(allowed, n) if filt(i) if filt(i)]
```

2) Use `np.fromiter`

```
arr = np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(allowed, n)), int).reshape(-1, n)
return arr[arr.sum(1) < 7]
```

3) work on the generator object itself. In the example above, you can stop the `itertools.combinations` when the first number is above 7 (as an example):

```
def my_generator():
    for i in itertools.combinations(allowed, n):
        if i[0] >= 7:
            return
        elif sum(i) < 7:
            yield i
list(my_generator())   # will build 3x times faster than option 1
```

Note that `np.fromiter` becomes less efficient on compound expressions, so the mask is applied afterwards

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.combinations(allowed_numbers, 6)` to get all combinations of length 6 from your list (this is the fastest way to get this operation done).

Comment: that's what OP is doing

Comment: Sorry, didn't see. He said he wanted a faster way to get combinations, but the `itertools` already provide the fastest way, so reading fast I thought he wasn't using it. For this reason i proposed my answer.